# Need To Translate One Line of Code in from C++ Qt to PyQt

Tags: python, c++, pyqt, translate, qmodelindex

What is the equivalent of this

```
QModelIndex index = ui->listView->currentIndex();
```

in Python, if my listView is self.listView

It's all I need to know, I spent hours trying to search for an answer for a question and I only found it in C++.

EDIT:

Basically, in PyQt, to access the index of QListView you need to use QModelIndex, so I'm confused as to how to apply the QModelIndex on the QListView.

Comment: Can you articulate what this line is doing in english? That'll help us identify what your code is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`index = self.listView.currentIndex()`